# JQuery JQPlot - customizing the stacked bar

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a unique requirement. 
1. Present a stacked bar chart
2. The color of each stack can be set by the user in the db
3. The user can check/uncheck to add or remove a stack from the graph
4. The user can change the order of the stacks.

1 and 2 are fine, but I am stuck at 3 and 4. I am thinking I will have to create a custom renderer for the legends, so that I can add a checkbox to it, but after that what?

Anyone done this? Or have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Once you created the renderer, you can bind some handler on the checkboxes' onclick event that would redraw the graph according to the user's choice.